# Hint: prove the order $k$ of the permutation $p$ is the LCM(lengths of each cycle)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, gcd-and-lcm, permutation-cycles

> Let $p$ be a permutation, and let $p^k$ denote the permutation arising
> by a k-fold composition of $p$. By the order of the permutation $p$ we
> mean the smallest natural number $k$ ≥ 1 such that $p^k = id$, where
> $id$ denotes the identity permutation (mapping each element onto
> itself). Show that each permutation $p$ of a finite set has a
> well-defined finite order, and show how to compute the order using the
> lengths of the cycles of $p$.

This is my first proof for a combinatorics class, and so I'm struggling to figure out how to actually write the proof. I did some examples, and I quickly figured out that the order $k$ of a permutation $p$ is the $LCM(L_1,L_2,\cdots,L_n)$ if we let $L_n$ equal the length of the nth cycle. If I prove that, then I think I answered the question because I (1) show how to compute the order and (2) show it's well-defined because there's only one LCM. But I just don't know how to prove that english statement, nor do I know how to translate that english sentence into mathematical language.

Comment: what happens if $k$ is not a multiple of one of the cycle lengths, and what happens if $k$ is a multiple of all the cycle lengths?

Comment: @Yorch (1) Let $k=aL+b$, where $0<b<L$. Then, $p^k(x)=p^{aL+b}(x)=p^{aL}p^{b}(x) \neq x$ (2) we get $p^k(x)=x$

Comment: Ok looks good, I suggest you try to write the proof with prose and then ask if it's ok, it most likely will be ok.

Comment: I think my problem is that I can answer those two questions, but I don't know how to formalize the thing I want to prove - the order $k$ of a permutation $p$ is the $LCM(L_1,L_2,\cdots,L_n)$ - in mathematical language

Comment: Maybe somtething like: We will prove $p^k$ is the identity if and only if $k$ is a multiple of all the cycle lengths. First assume $k$ is not a multiple of one of the cycle lengths, then this happens and so $p^k\neq id$. Now assume that $k$ is a multiple of every cycle length, then (do stuff here) , and so $p^k = id$. It follows the smallest positive $k$ such that $p^k=id$ is the least common multiple of the cycle lengths.

Comment: Thanks so much. The problem was that my phrasing **defined** the order to be $LCM(L_1,\cdots,L_n)$, whereas you turned it into something actually provable. How did you approach formalizing the english into math? And, why if and only if? Why not just if? Is it because if I defined something, it should be iff to show it goes both ways?

Comment: It's just practice, you'll get the hang of it after a little while. the if and only if is so that we can completely determine which values of $k$ work and which ones don't.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure ${}{}$